# How do you edit a file if you don't know if it exists yet without wiping the old one if there was one?

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to make a file and write stuff to it but only if it doesn't already exists. With my code, if the file does already exist, it wipes it and then writes to it.

I want to write to it without clearing the old info, but only if it previously existed.

This is the code I was trying:

```
def save_score():
    file = open('high_scores.txt', 'w+')
    file.write('name: '+name+', score: '+str(score)+'\n')
    file.close()
    file = open('high_scores.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    file.close()
    exit(0)

name = input('enter name ')
score = input('enter score ')
save_score()
```

Comment: use file = open("some.txt", "a") a stands for append so the old data will be intact

Comment: lol just realised you can use 'a+' but thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the "exists" method.... see https://linuxize.com/post/python-check-if-file-exists/

Answer (score 2):

The `open(“filename”, “mode”)` supports the following modes:

- ‘r’ – Read mode which is used when the file is only being read
- ‘w’ – Write mode which is used to edit and write new information to
  the file (any existing files with the same name will be erased when
  this mode is activated)
- ‘a’ – Appending mode, which is used to add new data to the end of the
  file; that is new information is automatically amended to the end
- ‘r+’ – Special read and write mode, which is used to handle both
  actions when working with a file

Use them according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Another way using os module.

````
import os
if os.path.isfile ('high_scores.txt'):
    print('The file exists')
else:
    print('The file does not exist')```
````